# Do not understand why the following query is wrong

Tags: sql, sybase

I am using Sybase and it complains the following has a syntax error:

```
DELETE
  *
FROM
  table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.some_col = table2.some_col
```

The specific error is: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'inner join'.`

I've checked online and this is how people go about it, but mine refuses to accept this.

Could someone please tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you intend to delete from table1 based on a join with table2 the following

```
DELETE table1
FROM
table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.some_col = table2.some_col
```

Comment: Is Sybase syntax similar to anothers? I find their documentation all very vague.

Comment: @czchlong - I've been using RDBMS for a very long time.  SyBase uses TSQL and *looks* a lot like MS SQL Server.  It's a trap.  There are so many differences that you're best to just assume it's totally unrelated and start your learning again (As if you're learning DB2 or Informix).

Comment: @Dems Thanks Dems, I've always used MySQL and I have learned to hate Sybase already.

Comment: @czchlong, not looking to sound parochial but you want to move off Sybase as soon as you can.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Sybase's Manual](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-iq/iqg1250e/iqref/@Generic__BookTextView/51140;pt=61646), it should be like this:

```
DELETE
FROM table1
FROM table1, table2
WHERE 
  table1.some_col = table2.some_col
```